# How to get all products from category with any price in OpenCart?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

```
$data = array(
        'filter_category_id'  => $category_id,
    );

    $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);
```

This is what I use to get all products by category ID.

I am developing a price slider for OpenCart 1.5.6 and I've noticed that whenever I do a query with a selected price range, the method above also gives me results in that price range.

What I need is to get all products from a specific category despite the price every time. How do I do this?

Comment: When I select values between 1 and 3, I also get values between 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working:

```
$products = $this->db->query("
SELECT p.price, ptc.*, ps.price as special 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX ."product p 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX ."product_to_category ptc 
ON p.product_id = ptc.product_id 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX ."product_special ps
ON p.product_id = ps.product_id
WHERE ptc.category_id ='$category_id'")->rows;
```

Using this query I always get all products from the specific category. (also included few other options to get special price).

Hope it will be useful for someone!